# Class Object Not Modifying Other Class Object Correctly

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to create a Model class that does the following:
- creates a Mesh class instance
- calls the addVertex function of the created Mesh object
- calls the addTriangle function of the created Mesh object

The Mesh class has two vectors to which the functions add to but when I print the contents in main.cpp they are empty.

Here is my code:

Model Class:

```
class Model 
{
public:
    /*  Model Data */
    /...

    //using default constructor

    Mesh createMesh() {
        Mesh mesh;
        meshes.push_back(mesh);
        return mesh;
    }

    void addVertex(Mesh mesh, Vertex v) {
        mesh.addVertex(v);
    }
    void addTriangle(Mesh mesh, Vertex a, Vertex b, Vertex c) {
        mesh.addTriangle(a,b,c);
    }
/...
```

Mesh Class:

```
class Mesh {
public:
    /*  Mesh Data  */
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vector<unsigned int> indices;
    /...
// constructor
    Mesh(vector<Vertex> vertices, vector<unsigned int> indices, vector<Texture> textures)
    {
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->indices = indices;
        this->textures = textures;
        for (Vertex v: vertices) {
            pairings.insert( std::pair<Vertex,unsigned int>(v,count) );
            count++;
        }
        setupMesh();
    }
    Mesh () {

    }

    //function 1
    void addVertex(Vertex vertex) {
        vertices.push_back(vertex);
        pairings.insert( std::pair<Vertex,unsigned int>(vertex,count));
        count++;
    }

    //function 2
    void addTriangle(Vertex a, Vertex b, Vertex c) { 
        unsigned int index = pairings[a];
        indices.push_back(index);
        index = pairings[b];
        indices.push_back(index);
        index = pairings[c];
        indices.push_back(index);
        setupMesh();
    }
```

main.cpp:

```
Model m;
    Mesh mesh = m.createMesh();
    Vertex a;
    a.Position = glm::vec3 (-1,0,0);
    m.addVertex(mesh, a);
    Vertex b;
    b.Position = glm::vec3 (0,1,0);
    m.addVertex(mesh,b);
    Vertex c;
    c.Position = glm::vec3 (1,0,0);
    m.addVertex(mesh,c);
    m.addTriangle(mesh,a,b,c);
    std::cout << mesh.indices.size(); //prints 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because on your `addVertex` and `addTriangle` methods within your Model class, you are passing the parameters by value, not by reference or pointer. This means that when you call the method you will pass a copy of your `Mesh` and `Vertex` objects and any changes you make inside the method will be lost as soon as execution of the method is complete. Try the following changes:

```
void addVertex(Mesh &mesh, Vertex &v) {
    mesh.addVertex(v);
}
void addTriangle(Mesh &mesh, Vertex &a, Vertex &b, Vertex &c) {
    mesh.addTriangle(a,b,c);
}
```

For more information on passing by reference, please refer to the [following](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).